# GoogleTest run_all_tests not finding test fixtures

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a C++ project that is going to be made up of only google tests. This project references another project (the project it is testing). I have a include and source folder for the header and implementation files. I am creating google test fixtures classes and split the header and implementation into the include and source folders. I have a main.cpp that contains the following code:

```
//main.cpp
#include "../inc/zeroEstimatorTest.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

The problem I am having is that the `RUN_ALL_TESTS()` call is not calling my google test fixture. The test fixture is located in the implementation of the test class. It looks like this:

```
//zeroEstimatorTest.cpp
class zeroEstimatorTest : public ::testing:Test
{
...
};

TEST_F(zeroEstimatorTest, zeroTest)
{
...
}
```

The project builds and runs but the output is the following:

```
[0;32m[==========] [mRunning 0 tests from 0 test cases.
[0;32m[==========] [m0 tests from 0 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[0;32m[  PASSED  ] [m0 tests.
```

I am currently using Eclipse (for the first time) and I am on a Linux 64 machine.

Things I have done:

- The zeroEstimatorTest class includes the `"zeroEstimatorTest.h"` at the top.
- The `#include "gtest/gtest.h"` is at the top of all three files (main.cpp, zeroEstimatorTest.h, and zeroEstimatorTest.cpp)

Can anyone help?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're not setting the tests filter name try initializing google test with --gtest_filter= it can be done using the main function parameters .

Comment: I have tried adding --gtest_filter=* to the debug configuration arguments inside Eclipse and it did not fix the problem. Is there something I did wrong? Otherwise I also looked at the google test primer and it says the following: "By default, a Google Test program runs all tests the user has defined."

Comment: Make sur that the  zeroestimatetest.cpp file is compiled with your test program, it can be the cause of your problem